# How to create shared folder between my on-premise Windows Server and Azure VM Server?

Tags: sql-server, migration, windows-server, azure-vm

I'm trying to migrate my on-premise SQL Server to Azure VM using 'Microsoft Data Migration Assistant'. But it is asking for shared folder to be accessed by both source and target. How to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to Azure I would suggest ticking the **"Copy the database backups to a different location that the target server can read and restore from"** and manually copy the backup files to the target.

I tried setting up an SMB share in Azure to use as the backup location as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-create-file-share) article. The issue I ran into was that Azure does not allow anonymous access to files share (the [request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/7188650-allow-anonymous-public-access-to-azure-file-storag) for the feature has been under review for more than 2 years)and you also can't enter the credentials in the Microsoft Data Migration Assistant, so this route doesn't seem like a solution at the moment.

The only other way I can think of is creating a permanent link with either ExpressRoute or VPN and then creating a share that can be accessed by both subnets.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a site to site VPN beteen the on-prem site and the Azure site. This would allow the Azure VMs to see all the same resources, then you can just migrate as expected.

Frankly I wouldn't use the Azure Migration Utility unless you're databases are pretty small as the outage may be longer than allowed for.  Setting up log shipping between the on-prem server and the Azure VM is probably the best bet. We do this for client's all the time and it works great.